# How to do exception handling while inserting data row by row in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In Python I am trying to read CSV file and renaming few columns before query building/inserting data and dropping few unwanted columns as well.
After that I am inserting data through pandas but it inserts data in bulk. **I wanted to track failed rows or rows having errors and not getting inserted in database.** so that I can put them in logger.
How to achieve this functionality in Python?

Comment: Don't do it with pandas. Just write an ordinary loop that calls `cursor.query()` separately for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying as follow.

```
mycursor = my_conn.cursor()

#open the csv file
with open(file_path, mode='r') as csv_file:
#read csv using reader class
  try:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  except:
    print("Error occurred while reading the file.")
    logging.error("Error occurred while reading the file.")
#skip header
  header = next(csv_reader)
  logging.info('Started row inserting.')
  #Read csv row wise and insert into table
  for row in csv_reader:
     del row[5]
     del row[3]
     del row[2]
     try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        mycursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
        my_conn.commit()
     except Exception as e:
          print(f"Error occurred while inserting row.{e}")
          logging.error(f"Error occurred while inserting record in DB.{row}")
          continue

mycursor.close()
logging.info('Row inserting finished.')
```